# Function as a returned value, Python

Tags: python, function

I am to return a function such that:

```
add1 = make_adder(1)
add1(5)
#Result: 6

make_adder(5)(10)
#Result: 15
```

I currently have

```
def make_adder(n):

    return lambda n: n+1

add1 = make_adder(1)
```

** Mistake noted!!*

BUT
I have another similiar question where I need to check where the numbers match each other.

```
def is_same(x,y): 
    return x == y 

def make_verifier(key): 
    return lambda n: is_same(262010771,key ) 
check_password = make_verifier(262010771)
```

If the key is having a different number, I am supposed to get a False, but I do not get where it is wrong

Comment: You should make another question, because you already have an accepted answer for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
def make_adder(n):
    return lambda x: n + x
```

As far as I can see, `make_adder(n)` should return a function that adds `n` to something that calls it. But what you have done is return `lambda n: n+1`, which is a function that adds 1 to something that calls it.

**More explanation**: In the first example, `add1` or `make_adder(1)` is a function that adds 1 to a value passed in. In the second example: `make_adder(5)` is a function by itself (which adds 5), and 10 is passed into this function to give 5 + 10.

`make_adder` by itself is a **function that creates a function** that adds n to a value passed in.

Answer (score 1):

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
>>> class Adder(int):
...     def __call__(self, number):
...             return self.__class__(self + number)
... 
>>> Adder(5)(10)
15
>>> Adder(5)(10)(15)
30
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_same(x,y): 
    return x == y 

def make_verifier(key): 
    return lambda n: is_same(n,key) 
check_password = make_verifier(262010771)
```

Instead of putting in the number `262010771`, you should put `n` to allow the flexibility to change `n` later in `check_password(262010771)`, if not it'll be fixed and always be *True*.